# Typescript: Assert type guard of object values

Tags: typescript

I have a method for checking if a variable is "empty" (null, undefined, '', [ ], { }, 0)

````
declare const emptyObjectSymbol: unique symbol;
type EmptyObject = { [emptyObjectSymbol]?: never };

/**
 * Return true if "value" is: null, undefined, '', [ ], { }, 0
 *
 * **Example**
 * 
 * ```js
 * const result = isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty(""); // return true
 * const result = isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty(null); // return true
 * const result = isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty(undefined); // return true
 * 
 * const result = isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty(new Date()); // return false
 * const result = isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty("Hello World"); // return false
 * ```
 */
export const isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty = (value: any): value is null | undefined | '' | [] | EmptyObject | 0 => {
  if (value === null || value === undefined || value === '' || value === 0) {
    return true;
  }
  if (typeof value === 'number' && isNaN(value)) {
    return true;
  }
  if (typeof value === 'object') {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      return value.length <= 0;
    } else {
      return Object.keys(value).length === 0 && value.constructor === Object;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
````

This works fine!

Now I want make a type guard that throws an error if a value into the record is empty:

```
function assertNonEmpty(params: T):
    asserts params is ??????????? {
    
    if (params === null || params === undefined) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid params`);
    }
    for (const key in params) {
        const value = params[key];
        if (isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty(value)) throw new Error(`Empty ${key}`);
    }
};
```

Comment: Your `EmptyObject` doesn't really work the way you want it to; TypeScript has no exact types, so there's no foolproof way to distinguish an empty object from one with no *known* properties.  If I write `const val = Math.random() < 0.5 ? {} : "abc"`, the compiler will infer that `val` is of type `{}` (all non-nullish values are assignable to `{}`), and there's no way for the compiler to, even in principle, distinguish the string case from the empty object case.  You'd need to explicitly mark all empty objects as being of type `EmptyObject`, but who's going to do that?

Comment: So, bearing the previous two comments in mind, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mMXY6N) might be one way to do it.  Does that fully address your question?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I have update the question with an example of use case

Comment: @jcalz I have delete your solution... tuo can post it as response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prologue and disclaimers**

Let's define a utility type so we don't have to use the expanded form all the time:

```
type Emptyish = null | undefined | '' | [] | EmptyObject | 0;
```

Also, in what follows, I will mostly ignore the complication where `EmptyObject` doesn't *really* prohibit properties. TypeScript can't, in general, prohibit unknown properties in the type system; this would require so-called *exact types* as requested in [ms/TS#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), but TypeScript doesn't have those.  There are a few features like [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) and [weak type detection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection) which give you *some* of that functionality, (indeed, you are using weak type detection in your definition of `EmptyObject`) but you can't rely on it.  If you write

```
const a = Math.random() < 0.5 ? {} : "hello";
```

the compiler will infer that `a` is of type `{}`, since `"hello"` is assignable to `{}` (all non-nullish values are), and therefore either the compiler treats `a` as `EmptyObject` or not, and neither way is going to give you the desired behavior.  So beware of `EmptyObject`.  I will work around this by writing something like

```
const emptyObject: EmptyObject = {};
const a = Math.random() < 0.5 ? emptyObject : "hello";
```

which the compiler can work with, even though this sort of thing is unlikely to happen in actual code.

Okay now we can begin in earnest.

---

**Main answer**

The main issue is that TypeScript doesn't have *negated types* of the form `not X` as implemented (but never released) in [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317).  So there's no simple way to say `not Emptyish`. If TypeScript *did* have negated types, you could possibly write:

```
// NOT VALID TS, DON'T WRITE THIS
function assertNonEmpty(params: Record<string, unknown>):
    asserts params is Record<string, not Emptyish>;
```

But it doesn't, so you can't.

Instead you will have to work around that by making `assertNonEmpty` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) that maps over each property of `params` and filters its type to exclude any `Emptyish` [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) members.

It's not necessarily perfect (e.g., `string` will stay `string` and does not exclude `""`; `number` will stay `number` and does not exclude `0`... there is no `number & not 0`), but it might be sufficient for your use cases.  It would look like this:

```
declare function assertNonEmpty<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(params: T):
    asserts params is { [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], Emptyish> };
```

Here we're asserting that `params` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) using [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) for each property.

Let's test it out:

```
const emptyObject: EmptyObject = {};
const foo = {
    a: Math.random() < 0.5 ? undefined : "abc",
    b: Math.random() < 0.5 ? emptyObject : "hello"
};
/* const foo: {
    a: string | undefined;
    b: string | EmptyObject;
} */

foo.a.toUpperCase(); // error, 
//~~~ <-- foo.a is possibly undefined
foo.b.toUpperCase(); // error, 
//    ~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- toUpperCase does not appear on EmptyObject
```

So here we have `foo`, an object with two possibly empty properties, and you are not allowed to treat them as non-empty.  Now let's run our assertion function:

```
assertNonEmpty(foo);

foo;
/* const foo: {
    a: string;
    b: string;
} */

console.log(
    foo.a.toUpperCase(),
    foo.b.toUpperCase()
); // "ABC", "HELLO" if you get here
```

You can see that, after the function is called, `foo` has been narrowed to `{a: string, b: string}`, and you are allowed to treat each member as a `string` by the compiler.  `Emptyish` has been eliminated, as desired!

---

This implementation looks good for this particular use case.  Again, it could easily fail depending on what use cases you need to support.  And *maybe* there are tweaks that would work with those use cases.  But without true negated types (and true exact types for that matter), there's probably always going to be a mismatch somewhere.  So you should test thoroughly against the situations you care about, and be prepared for some refactoring and/or some relaxing of your requirements.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3iAtgBwwE8B5AIwCtwMBlQnUpCALngFcUBLAR1YTToYQA3ACgieBAFF8RMpTBYAvPADe8ANq4CJClVr1GAXQD8LFCABuIGPAC+osYQnxp2jmgAW8ZSlYQI8AA+bCigAGYc5sBB8ADksTHqhjGusroKMQAMogD0AFR5IvB58ABKIBisMCjwGDC88Bxh8ABEFlAQvC2NaGZ+EAA0IeGRIMBD8UPq8IZDarZDmUWFxcV5kgAeUPgQIAXL8AcABifkaAfI6FhwaH5KPQBy-cQwAKqhIBFRL6mEABQtFoASiE8ByOXgcEq1Vq9RAF1QmEhIFuEHu7ie-he7xG3xgvz+vn8ILBEKhVRqdV4CKuyNR6LQmIg2I+XzGPxk-3YuLGJPByOhlLhBxpSJud28j2eb1Zo2AHO0hJAAHd4AARKAYEB-IF8skVCnwMIdNDw1aXMUoiXKDHSnGfOUKogAgASIH8SHgAHUkDAIMBgaD+eSYcaIKbjidljkRBasLasTKefL8ZzJX92p0QCwoChCECWJmGu4XJz3F5FAA+VRFeB1prwDMdBqKVvwIkBQLBIsIVvKbkOqJBbvN3tt+LD+A97xtzJAmt1xeLkNC3iiJe2Wv15p-cQgJDNad9uK+ejWBIAMgvjygDybWd1C6Xy4NMKpIHXi83S4bu6c+8PUcZ2UWIkHSDBYnnFQt2fX8AEEYBgKBCAAOncBCkP+HtH2g588IFQ0exQ3YUAAcwwLwAB5lGyGCN2wcMEFw-ClxXeA5CoFCAGsQEINB714IFiJAMiKOA+BMngK8p1HFC43qBRfXEjiFE-PDvy-GC2LDU1RHsEQRHyQyIQeYgABV4AANTggAZABJNV4DM6ghjVYgHliCyvVKOyzMkJyXTs6gRDCdgFA4VB4CgNBTRgDAHlQAk8FgbZejKcBfWASjMBgSJSKGdguJQJBlRQSsCxg6LYowNB4GSpCcFqktymQGAspyvKhmKrBfnLStRDyGMQrCjAIpqKrrHixLOUoiyQA2LVQlqlrMuyupOpCIqSrKys-nq1KWDMiqlwmuLav2xqelUDQAGlGhqHjCAPJzDBYTZIFYUBZvUG7ZlLNxPGrfThpQcLItOqaUCSlLGpYFa2rW3KyIKlAttK8qn23RsLtq48O0nHHxIHNlgCgujFwomASvbFUXEQ30-iOOyUEzDhohxo4QRgjS6zCJS-jjeBHvuuqYbQMmWMFo9RYatB1Eeww1NgncE2ZJNB3ZVNFWw+dKep8xVUkemYEZ354AAEhUR7bE5pXN2BgzY0RLAtDSeQMDezkVPuFR9MFvnPWUZi6ygFgAFlNQ8FCkNCJAcB1eBKIklCAFZ4GMYYNeiFgWigUgwBaAYYNIcPI+j3NgDjhOk8yVP0+wL3wPgHOPHdCAkBaER9PyRBnaNJAkBYYOopYDqyJiYm5SVkv4DH0iUkb929OKIa6kITH+6QFCoBQjAkFePAJBgABhaLtT1bBjaGAPt6uvAkBijhSAgdfJ6iGCb9IXf98P6xT9NHUQYITWCpjAIYe8D5H3-ggSuKJ2xICwFAX+sB4CRV+N7LuiBNRgC8H8EAEtFwWkYCAYiSBSJ4KBF3EQEMEpQ05H8AOXMA65BKP7AeQ9Kqj3WmRaeXCkakWXoNJ26BiGkPIR-Ae29v6QL-mfHURclyf2kb-E+cjKEXxaHBAAQsfQurQXSSBsjZYg3QGxPVYPAUiFR4CtzgEAA)